# Oracle ApEX website

Tags: oracle-apex

I plan to create a website using Oracle ApEX and have a question regarding security, authentication.

Most of the pages are going to be public to anyone, but some of them will require authentication. My question is that what is the guideline to handle this? If I enable an authentication scheme on application level then I guess each visitor will land directly on the login page when visiting the website, which is not good. I plan to place a login box in a region of the public pages, so users can login/register if they want.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I was able to solve this with a built-in functionality.

In ApEX you can have pages that are public though the authentication is enabled at application level. You have to set the Page Attributes -> Authentication to Page Is Public for the pages which are going to be public. For the pages which are not public you have to set the Page Attributes -> Authentication to Page Requires Authentication (which is set by default at page creation). So, when the user accesses public pages the application will not ask for authentication, but when (s)he tries to access pages with authentication set, it will ask for credentials.

Comment: Thank you happy new years 2020